# Ruby-on-Rails Rake import unexpected tASSOC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rake

I'm trying to load data from a csv as a rake task with the following code:

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import Users from csv file"
task :import_users => [:environment] do

file = "db/users.csv"

CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
User.create {
  :name => row[1],
  :email => row[2],
  :password => row[3],
  :password_confirmation => row[4],
  :admin => row[5]
}
end

end
```

and the CSV:

```
name,email,password,password_confirmation,admin
john smith,js@mail.com,password,password,TRUE
```

im getting the a unexpected tASSOC error for each attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put brackets around your hash in the create method it will work fine:

```
User.create({
  :name => row[1],
  :email => row[2],
  :password => row[3],
  :password_confirmation => row[4],
  :admin => row[5]
})
```

Basically ruby doesn't understand that this is a method call with a hash as the parameter. By putting the brackets there you make it explicit that that is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately this now errors with Don't know how to build this task. when i run rake import_users_csv:import_users the file is called import_users_csv.rake

Comment: The name of your file doesn't get included in the rake tasks so you should probably just be calling `rake import_users`. You can look at the tasks available with `rake -T` to check whether rake it picking it up too.